# How to find request param in nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, nginx-reverse-proxy, conf.d

Regarding nginx reverse proxy I am struggling to get the parameters values from the request URL in NGINX conf.d

My URL is [https://abcd.cloudfront.net/app/dashboards#/view/aa501030-e93e-11eb-bdcf-531cdb7c714a?param1="somecryptedvalue=="](https://abcd.cloudfront.net/app/dashboards#/view/aa501030-e93e-11eb-bdcf-531cdb7c714a?param1=%22somecryptedvalue==%22)

here aa501030-e93e-11eb-bdcf-531cdb7c714a in URL is the dynamic part.
I just need the value of param1.

the below code worked fine for me if URL is just [https://abcd.cloudfront.net?param1="somecryptedvalue=="](https://abcd.cloudfront.net?param1=%22somecryptedvalue==%22)

if ($args ~ "^url=(.+)") { #gets the "url" get parameter
set $key1 $1;

}

Comment: Anything after the `#` character is the [**URL fragment**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) and is not received by the server, so Nginx never sees it.

Comment: Thanks Richard ,So is it possible if I am sending without Hash and setting hash in my proxy_pass, actually i am using reverse proxy to add Kibana link and hash is required for it.